# Could someone explain the convergence analysis step a bit further for Newton's Method $g(x) = 1/x^2 − x/R $

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

So the function has $r = \sqrt[3]{R}$ as a zero for any positive real number R.

$$g(x) = 1/x^2 − x/R $$
Determine derivatives:
$$g'(x)= -2/x^3 -1/R$$
$$g''(x)= 6/x^4$$

So I get for newtons iteration:
$$x_{n+1} = 3Rx_{n}/(2R+ x_{n}^3)$$

Now this is some explanation i got but I dont follow.

Convergence analysis: consider $x > 0$ only. The function $g(x) $is monotone decreasing, convex diverging to $−∞$
when $x → ∞$. If $0 < x_{n} < r$, then $g(x_{n}) > 0$. Because of the decreasing convex properties, $x_{n} < x_{n+1} < r$, and
from this $x_{n} → r$. Calculus shows that
$x_{0} > r ⇒ 0 < x_{1} < r.$

Thus, convergence for all $x > 0.$

Comment: Could you add some more steps? I get for the Newton step function $$N_g(x)=x-\frac{g(x)}{g'(x)}=x+x\frac{R-x^3}{2R+x^3}=x\frac{(2R+x^3)+(R-x^3)}{2R+x^3}=\frac{3Rx}{2R+x^3}.$$

Comment: Oh damn I copied the wrong one , you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the function $g$ is strictly convex implies that the tangents are all below the graph of the function. This in particular means that where the tangent $t_k$ at $x_k$, $$t_k(x)=g(x_k)+g'(x_k)(x-x_k)\le g(x),$$ has its root $x_{k+1}$, the function value is positive, $g(x_{k+1})>t_k(x_{k+1})=0$. So if you start at a point $x_0<r$ where the function $g$ is positive, then the Newton iterate $x_1$ will lie between this point and the root, giving monotonicity.

If $x_0>r>0$, then the Newton step formula shows that the tangent root $x_1=\frac{3Rx_0}{2R+x_0^3}$ is positive, from the convexity it follows that the function value $g(x_1)$ has to be positive, which implies $x_1<r$.

Comment: Okay thanks but how then does this follow. Calculus shows that x0>r⇒0<x1<r.

Thus, convergence for all x>0.

Comment: Use the mean inequality AM-GM to find $$\frac{2R+x_0^3}3\ge r^2x_0,$$ then insert into $$x_1=\frac{3r^3x_0}{2r^3+x_0^3}\le\frac{r^3x_0}{r^2x_0}=r.$$

Comment: Man i feel kinda dumb but how did you arrive at $\frac{2R+x_0^3}3\ge r^2x_0$ , with AM-GM and how do we see $x_{0}>r$

Comment: Using $\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}3\ge\sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3}=abc$. Use that $2R+x_0^2=r^3+r^3+x_0^3$.

Comment: pff  i was using $\sqrt[3]{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}$ Thanks so much for your patience!